HOWTO Rye python package manager development workflow
when using either rye or poetry with pyo3 & maturin to develop a rust crate with python bindings to develop a wheel/sdist library ..
is there a way to configure the dependencies in pyproject.toml of another project to automatically load the latest development code without having to bump the version in pyproject (or cargo.toml if version=['dynamic'] and avoid needing to do an add/remove using poetry to install the new project.
I'm hoping for something like a pip -e workflow so I can be developing concurrently on a Rust library + a python invoker of the library.
Right now this process works but is rather tedious.
If I figure this out I'll post an answer.

Wait, why do you need to specify version in cargo.toml, and not just path? Separate repo's? If you run maturin develop it doesn't build rust part as well?
